# Javascript Error : "cannot read property of Id undefined"

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I have a custom button which is using the javascript code given below. I am getting the error that it is not able to get the Id. Please suggest where am in going wrong.
"cannot read property of Id undefined".

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/25.0/connection.js")}
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}

    var orderObj = new sforce.SObject("MiC_Order__c"); 
    orderObj.Id = '{!Order__c.Id}'; 
    var recType = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id from RecordType where developername = 'Consumer_Open'");
    var records = recType.getArray("records");
    orderObj.RecordTypeId = records[0].Id;
    sforce.connection.update([orderObj]);

    window.location.reload();
```

Comment: Have you check which line is throwing the error? If not use `alert()` and check for it. I'm suggesting you to replace `orderObj.Id` with `orderObj.id` and try

Comment: Are you sure the query is returning any results? The issue is coming mostly at the line `orderObj.RecordTypeId = records[0].Id;` because the records has no data and you're trying to the Id property of records. Try putting an `alert (records)` or write the records to the console using `console.log('the records are '+ records)`.